# Programmatically add posts from specific category to menu

Tags: posts, categories, menus

I am wanting to add individual posts to my primary menu programatically based on category

I have used the wp_nav_menu_items filter previously to add pages to the menu but I am stuck when it comes to adding posts.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'fx_user_menu', 10, 2 );

function fx_user_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $myposts = get posts from specified category
            foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
            $items .= '<li><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . the_title() . '</a></li>';
            }
    }   
    return $items;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I get you right, but maybe this will solve your problem:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'fx_user_menu', 10, 2 );

function fx_user_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $myposts = get_posts( array(
            'category' => <YOUR CATEGORY ID GOES HERE>,
            'posts_per_page' => 5
        ) );

        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
            // you should not use the_title and the_permalink outside of The Loop - they won't work correctly
            $items .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title) . '</a></li>';
        }
    }   
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. But will you be kind enough to show how to add this under a specific  menu item as submenu?